# Is there a way to put all external libraries into one folder?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jar, jsoup, libraries

For example, in the picture I have a 1.8 folder and a separate maven folder. Is there anyway that I can put the jsoup.jar in the maven folder into the 1.8 folder in Intellij? In other words, is there a way to have ALL my external libraries only in that 1.8 folder? Thanks! [image: libraries]

Answer (score 2):

**Do not manually manage the dependency in IDE when using a build tool like Maven or Gradle etc.**

Regarding the two folders of libraries displayed in IntelliJ

1. `<1.8>` folder is from the JRE which is required to run any Java application.
2. `Maven` is generated based on the dependencies from the `pom.xml`.

Note: The folder displayed in IntelliJ is a logical representation not an actual folder in the filesystem.

> Is there a way to put all external libraries into one folder?

Technically you can put all the dependency in a single folder and configure your IDE to load the libraries from that folder but *in your case you don't need to  do that maven will take care of that*.